# how to exclude `RSA, SF, DSA` while extracting jar in intelliJ?

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea, jar, junit4

I saw this SOF [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592057/error-while-creating-consolidated-jar-file-no-manifiest-section-for-signature)

I'm experiencing the same problem.

I'm using intelliJ as IDEA without Ant manifest to create the jar.
How can I achieve the same using intelliJ ?

```
<jar destfile="build/xpath.jar" basedir="bin">
    <restrict>
        <not>
            <or>
                <name name="**/*.RSA"/>
                <name name="**/*.SF"/>
                <name name="**/*.DSA"/>
            </or>
        </not>
        <archives>
            <zips>
                <fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
            </zips>
        </archives>
    </restrict>
</jar>
```